# Embedded IFrame domain restrictions

Tags: security, iframe, dns, cross-domain

I have an IFrame that will be embedded onto my clients websites. Ideally I'd like to limit the iframe to their domains. I have implemented the Content Security Policy "Content-Security-Policy frame-ancestors example.com" header which seems to get the job done quite well, but a simple change in the hosts file makes that domain accessible...

I have looked into HTTP referrer etc, and found most of the common solutions to be easily bypassed, especially by just changing the hosts file.

So my questions are:

1. Is there any other way to restrict the render of an iframe to a specific domain?
2. Is there anyway to determine that a client is not connecting from the actual domain name specified?

Thanks Guys

Comment: Why are you worried about the hosts file? An attacker cannot change a user's host file without another attack vector. It shouldn't be a risk if an attacker changes their own hosts file because they can only attack themselves. If your application is trusting client-side information then it shouldn't if it is a risk if it is altered.

Comment: Essentially I want to white list `example.com` to be able to embed my iframe. Once you change the hosts file, you can emulate being example.com, and thus load the frame locally.

Comment: There's nothing you can do about this - all the data is client-side. A user who wanted to frame your site on their own machine could disable security checks on their browser anyway or manipulate headers via an intercepting proxy.